# 1NF - trying to understand the wiki article

Tags: sql

I know what is 1NF in practice, this are my rules when designing DB. I have not done much on enterprise level, but my designs till now have done well. I check following when taking care of 1NF. Let me take the example of a phonebook where people have multiple email addresses and multiple contact numbers like home, mobile, work1, work2 and can add more.

This is my schema, not normalized: 
phonebook
first_name, middle_name, last_name, email_1, email_2, email_3(may be more will be added in future), mobile_1, mobile_2, work_1, work_2, (and more will get added).

1. If data is getting duplicated in a column say email_address then it has to be moved to a separate table email details and the id has to be used in the master table.
2. I avoid groups, say when people have multiple email accounts like email_1, email_2 to avoid querying how many email addresses a person is having or performing deletion.
3. Always put a primary key to uniquely identify a row, this assists in deletion of records.

As per First Normal Form

1. There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.
2. There's no left-to-right ordering to the columns.
3. There are no duplicate rows.
4. Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else).
5. All columns are regular [i.e. rows have no hidden components such as row IDs, object IDs, or hidden timestamps].

I am not able to understand the meaning of this points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.
> 2. There's no left-to-right ordering to the columns.

This is just a fundamental tenet in the relational world: all sets and relations represented by the table rows and columns are unordered. You should not have any dependency on the particular order of rows or columns within your code.

> 1. There are no duplicate rows.

Relations should be unique, otherwise you will soon have data integrity problem. Imagine what would happen if your phonebook contained your friend's data twice! When your friend changes his phone number, one of the associated rows surely gets updated, but the other probably not. Now guess what happens when people try to look up his phone number...

> 1. Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else).

I.e. you shouldn't contain values like `"x,y,z"`, where a single text field is in fact composed of a list of more primitive values.

1. All columns are regular [i.e. rows have no hidden components such as row IDs, object IDs, or hidden timestamps].

I believe this says that your rows should be identified only by their key(s), and these should be "normal", full column values, not contained within e.g. markup text.

Comment: Does a duplicate row means that only email_1 is getting replicated across rows or does it means that the entire data from the row is getting duplicated.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, actually both the answers are correct. But I like this one as it keeps things in the context of the phonebook schema.

Comment: @Pradeep, a duplicate row means the entire data in a row is duplicated. An email address may appear in several rows without violating data integrity. E.g. an email account at a free email provider used to belong to Adam but got deleted, than at some later point Bill created a new account with the same address. A DB containing both persons' address is arguably not up to date, but no integrity constraint is violated. Another example may be simply that a computer illiterate grandmother uses her grandson's email address (and skills) to communicate with the world.

Answer (score 2):

1&2 are saying that the order the data is presented does not matter.  There aren't rows or columns that are indicating what kind of data should be in other rows or columns.

3 is pretty self-explanatory.

4 means you aren't storing a combination of data in a field, ie an AnimalAndVegetable with values like 'HorsePear', instead you'd have an Animal column and a Vegetable column.

5 is similar to 4, it just means you aren't parsing through field values to get the "real" data, ie storing a field that contains an id surrounded by tokens that are to be discarded before the id is used

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply I will accept the answer that explains the 1 and 2 in relation to the schema mentioned by me.